# iOS - Load UIViewController in Specific Orientation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation

What i'm trying to do - is simply **force start my ViewController in Portrait mode** regardless of its orientation:

after its initiated, it could just continue to follow the AutoRotate functionality

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645010/force-uiview-uiviewcontroller-orientation) is probably along the answer I'm looking for : but the answer contains a broken link

---

---- if interested, the reason i need this is:

- i'm creating a PDF Reader in a UIView
- in Portrait mode it can use the screen dimensions to load the PDF proportionately
- the UIView is set to `UIViewAutoReSizingNone` and `UIViewContentModeLeft`
- this presents the PDF perfectly when the device Orientation changes to landscape (of course I'm handling panning / zooming / positioning of the PDF separately for a better presentation)
- But when I launch the VC in landscape I have problems . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Look at fixing your auto resizing / auto layout rules and initial view size so rotation works both ways. And or look at using `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` (you would need a flag to limit the orientation during display of the new view controller and then a mechanism to reset that flag after the display was done - which could result in weird rotations, so just fix the auto layout...).

Comment: I've been messing about with AutoLayout for a long time before posting this question :/  . . . . - the issue is more complicated because I have UITexFields placed on top on the UIView . . . . Resizing in anyway distorts their positions

Comment: I'd suggest you raise a question and show your view hierarchy and all layout rules rather than this question (which is the wrong way to approach the problem).